# Convert Image into Flag

Tags: jython

I have to change any given picture into the Pride flag.

To do so, my current code is:

`pixels = getPixels(picture)
 width = getWidth(picture)
 height = getHeight(picture)
 for index in range(0,len(pixels)/7):
    pixel = pixels[index]
    setColor(pixel,red)
 for index in range(len(pixels)/7,len(pixels)):
     pixel = pixels[index]
     setColor(pixel,orange)
 for index in range(2*len(pixels)/7,len(pixels)):
     pixel = pixels[index]
     setColor(pixel,yellow)`

Note: *I have not included the entire code snippet, it continues on in that same manner.*

The problem is that the lines colours are interjecting into each other and it shows up as this:
[image]

What could be causing this and how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem there is an uneven about of pixels for the line divisions you are doing. Find out how many pixels there are for each line then use that in your `for` loops. For example...

```
no_pixels_per_line = len(pixels) / height

for index in range(0, (height/7) * no_pixels_per_line):
   pixel = pixels[index]
   setColor(pixel,red)

etc...
```